# Can I track all users' file access on GCP, i.e. when file was downloaded, read, etc?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, file-storage

I want to upload a document to gcp google cloud storage but I want to know whenever that file is downloaded for security purposes, i.e. I don't want someone downloaded file locally without knowing.

Comment: if you do not want to be downloaded you should create policies for read/write, the easiest way is going to the file, click on the thre dot at the right and select "edit permissions"

Comment: your point of view is wrong, is like a bank had it's door opened where all the money is, having a bunch of cameras around just to "see who is taking the money", and of course not security guard

Answer (score 1):

If your Cloud Storage object is public, Google Cloud does not log or track access.

If you put a CDN in front of the bucket, and then use the CDN URL, Stackdriver will log access via the CDN.

Answer (score 0):

If you intend to stop people from downloading it, IAM & Bucket permissions are what you're looking for.

If its to Monitor Access for an audit trail, you can check the logs in StackDriver by filtering to GCS and looking for your bucket/file.

The log viewer filtering details are described [here](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/view/overview):